Do Helium-4 atoms behave like photons?
I know that the Helium-4 atom is a boson. Does this mean that, like photons, many Helium-4 atoms can be placed at the same point in space?
How its possible? It includes fermions (Protons, Neutrons, and Electrons), which do not act this way.
Also, I wonder if in the non-inertial frames we use the Klein–Gordon equation for Helium-4 atoms?

The electromagnetic field is massless (at least as far as we know), so no, it does not behave like massive bosons, which form Bose-Einstein condensates.

See Superfluid helium-4

A helium 4 atom is a boson only if you are looking at it on a scale much larger that the radius of the atom. If you start looking closely you'll start to see it is a composite object made up from fermions.
So as a very rough guide the helium atom behaves like a boson only when the uncertainty in its position, $\Delta x$, is much larger than its radius. From the uncertainty principle this means the uncertainty in its momentum must be very small, and since we can only get a small $\Delta p$ at low temperatures this means the helium atom will behave like a boson only at low temperatures.
The obvious examples of this are superfluidity and formation of a Bose-Einstein condensate, and indeed we only see these at temperatures close to absolute zero.
So the answer to your question is that helium atoms can indeed occupy the same place in space, as we'd expect from a boson, but only under conditions when they are so highly delocalised in space that the fine details of the fermions inside them is averaged away.
